# How to route to a page with the same name

Tags: reactjs

I am using this statement to route to a page

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/about`}
  component={asyncComponent(() => import('./routes/about'))}/> 
<Route>
```

But I have many pages (about, location, ....)
How can I route to the page without specifying every page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify all the routes if you want them to be available on different routes.

You can create a separate file routes.js which will have all the routes for the application. Then import this in App.js.